# while publishing customization project on acumatica 22R1 instance I am getting error

Tags: acumatica, acumatica-kb

> System.Exception: An error occurred while copying files to the temp
> directory  ---> System.IO.IOException: Cannot create "C:\Program
> Files\Acumatica
> ERP\Customization\AcumaticaMfg2022R1\AcumaticaMfg2022R1Validation\AcumaticaMfg2022R1Website\Bin"
> because a file or directory with the same name already exists.    at
> System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be a permissions issue, most likely due to being installed under Program Files.

Per the training material, you are encouraged not to install Acumatica under Program Files because of potential permissions issues.  I suspect this is the issue you face now.  I'd suggest a backup of your source code and making a snapshot of your tenant(s), uninstall Acumatica and then reinstall into C:\Acumatica ERP and then recreate your AcumaticaMfg2022R1 instance there.  Alternatively, you can try to get the necessary permissions onto your instance where it exists, but you may fight this same battle again.

Comment: Thanks I will try this ....But I have some other instance for that also I have Installed Acumatica ERP under Programs Files folder and that all instance working fine.